# Javascript ES6 reference a variable in the global scope but not in the window scope

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, window, global

I am upgrading my code from ES5 to ES6.  In ES5 I dynamically load the function by creating a new script which then loads the file asynchronously.  the code is as follows:

```
loadClass : function(className) {
    if(typeof window[className] !== "function") {
        page.getCode(className, dirName);
        return;
    } ...


getCode(className) {
    var fileName = className.toLowerCase();
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    newScript.setAttribute("src", '/public/js/' + fileName + '.js');
    var parmArr = [className];
    newScript.addEventListener('load', this.loadClass.bind("", parmArr));
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
    return;
}
```

In ES5 the function is loaded in the global scope which in this case is window. I have the function/class name in a string and I can reference the class using window[classname] as shown in the code above.  In ES6 I changed the calling and called functions to a class.  Now when it loads the script it exists as Myclass function() in the global scope but not in the window scope as shown in the Chrome debugger like so:

```
Myclass ()
[[Scopes]] : Scopes[2]
    0 : Script
        Myclass () : ()
```

I can no longer reference it with a variable as window[classname].  Grasping at straws I also tried [classname], global[classname] and Global[classname] and this[classname] and script[classname] but that does not work.

In ES6, how do I test if it is already loaded when the classname is in a variable ?  This is probably something really easy, but it is eluding me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean that it is an actual ES6 class, then your only option would be `eval`. Since you're the one responsible for loading the class, couldn't you track the loaded values in a separate object instead though?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: yes good point.  When I load my own classes in PHP I keep track of loaded classes in an array.  I need to create a loader class for js as well.  The eval does work but has to be wrapped in a try/catch because it errors out.   Thanks.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: oops, even if I create a loader class and add the name to an array once loaded, I still have to be able to test if the class exists using a variable name.  In PHP there is a function class_exists, but there does not seem to be similar functionality in JS.  I tried instanceof and testing for the class method but that does not seem to work either.  So far only eval wrapped in a try/catch works but using eval seems to be a klughy fix.  Thanks

Comment: It's a kludgy fix because this approach to loading stuff isn't a good idea :) Unless you really want to be maintaining this all yourself, I'd recommend looking into Webpack. Loading stuff into the global scope isn't a good idea, so there isn't a ton of reason to make it easy to do.

Comment: @loganfsmyth:  Thanks for your ideas so far.  I do want to maintain this myself.  You mention this approach is not a good idea.  Is there another approach to loading a class from a file into the browser dynamically ?  I do have a dynamic loader but it also uses eval to parse the file so that's also not desirable.  What do you recommend for an approach ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given your current approach, it would probably be relatively easy for you to transition to AMD modules. That approach is like 5 years old though. These days though most people would bundle all of your code together ahead of time using Webpack, so you'd just load all the files up front. Is there a specific reason you want to load each file when it is requested? That's also workable with Webpack, but it's more complicated.

Comment: Given the possibility of bumping up against browser memory limits, I would only want to load resources if they are needed.  I would not want to load all my classes up front if only a few are needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how ES6 works... To avoid polluting the global object (here `window`), your JavaScript code does not create global properties anymore (unless you are explicit). In ES5, these properties were created automatically when using `var` or `function` in the global scope. With `let`, `const` or `class`, nothing happens. Consider this example:

```
// ES5

var foo;

function qux() {}

console.log('foo' in window); // true
console.log('qux' in window); // true

// ES6

let bar;
const baz = '';

class Quux {}

console.log('bar' in window); // false
console.log('baz' in window); // false
console.log('Quux' in window); // false

window.bar = bar;
window.baz = baz;
window.Quux = Quux;

console.log('bar' in window); // true
console.log('baz' in window); // true
console.log('Quux' in window); // true
```

Comment: so you're saying it cannot be done?  There is no way to check if a class exists if the class name is in a string ?

Comment: I just wanted to check if what you did say could be done and it can! If you do it like this: window.foo = new foo(). If you then do: console.log('foo' in window) it returns true :-)